# How to print Nim's AST at runtime?

Tags: macros, nim-lang

[`dumpTree`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/macros.html#dumpTree.m%2Cuntyped) and similar macros print Nim's AST at *compile* time. I was wondering how to print the same content at **runtime**. The use case is to be able to capture the output to document it in a [nimib](https://github.com/pietroppeter/nimib) document.

To have a concrete example:

```
import macros

dumpTree:
  25 ⬇️
  10 ➖
```

produces at compile time:

```
StmtList
  Command
    IntLit 25
    Ident "⬇️"
  Command
    IntLit 10
    Ident "➖"
```

I would like a `dumpTreeRuntime` that is equivalent for the above case to:

```
echo """
StmtList
  Command
    IntLit 25
    Ident "⬇️"
  Command
    IntLit 10
    Ident "➖"
"""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import macros


macro treeToString(code: untyped): untyped =
   return newLit(treeRepr(code))


when isMainModule:
  let x = treeToString:
    25 ⬇️
    10 ➖

   echo(x)
```